# How do I encode (GZIP) the response of a rejected path?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am attempting to ensure all responses from the server are encoded/compressed via GZIP. It works great for defined paths but I have been unable to figure out how to achieve the same for "Rejected" paths.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.coding.Gzip
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object Test extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  val route =
    encodeResponseWith(Gzip) {
      path("hello") {
        get {
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, "world"))
        }
      }
    }

  val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)

  Await.result(bindingFuture, Duration.Inf)
}
```

Response (compressed when route is found)

```
http http://localhost:8080/hello
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 17:54:40 GMT
Server: akka-http/2.4.6
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

world
```

Response (NOT compressed when route is NOT found - AKA rejected)

```
http http://localhost:8080/hell0
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 42
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 17:57:50 GMT
Server: akka-http/2.4.6

The requested resource could not be found.
```

**UPDATE**

Even with a RejectionHandler, the response is unaffected.

```
implicit def myRejectionHandler = RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
  .handleNotFound {
    encodeResponseWith(Gzip) {
      complete((NotFound, "Not here!"))
    }
  }.result()
```

yields

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 9
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 18:10:47 GMT
Server: akka-http/2.4.6

Not here!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an implicit `RejectionHandler`, as described in the [official documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.6/scala/http/routing-dsl/rejections.html#Customizing_Rejection_Handling)

```
implicit def myRejectionHandler = RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
  .handleNotFound {
    encodeResponseWith(Gzip) {
      complete((NotFound, "Not here!"))
    }
  }.result()
```

Comment: I've tried that but the response is not affected: 
`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 9
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 18:10:47 GMT
Server: akka-http/2.4.6

Not here!
`

Comment: Just double checked, and you're right. This definitely looks like a bug in akka-http. Initially akka-http was a fork of [spray](http://spray.io/), and most of the DSL is the same. I've just written the same logic for a spray-based server, and encoding setting for the rejectionHandler worked fine there, but this is not the case with akka-http. I dug a little into the internals of akka-http and found that it does actually find the encoder, but then it somehow gets lost, and the resulting response is then not encoded.

Comment: I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20648) about this to akka on github